# Replace lines in multiple files matching a pattern with lines from another file in order

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to replace the lines matching a pattern from multiple files from the lines in order from another file, i have up to 500 txt files, with structure:
**test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt...**

```
11111
22222
mock
55555
77777
```

and so reading file one by one we like to replace in first test1.txt file mock line with first line from mock.txt file, in second test2.txt replace mock line with second line from mock.txt file, which has structure like:

**mock.txt**

```
randomText1
randomText2
randomText3
randomText4
randomText5
```

and so on till the last .txt file in filder

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?

Comment: im completely new to this field, i was searching for similar cases but its kinda far from what im looking for

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed, you can use

```
cat mock.txt | sed -i -e '/mock/{R/dev/stdin' -e 'd;}' test{1..3}.txt
```

The GNU specific `R` command reads and inserts a *single* line at a time, unlike the standard `r` option which would insert all of the contents.

```
$ head test{1..3}.txt
==> test1.txt <==
11111
22222
randomText1
55555
77777

==> test2.txt <==
11111
22222
randomText2
55555
77777

==> test3.txt <==
11111
22222
randomText3
55555
77777
```

> ```
> R filename
> ```
>
> Queue a line of filename to be read and inserted into the output stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next input line is
>   read. Note that if filename cannot be read, or if its end is reached,
>   no line is appended, without any error indication.
>
> As with the r command, the special value /dev/stdin is supported for the file name, which reads a line from the standard input.

*Note that reading the lines directly from the file like `/mock/R mock.txt` doesn't work in this context, because the `-i` option implies the `-s` option, so that the first line of `mock.txt` is inserted into every file.*

Comment: Thank you, that works well, but if i have lines like this sometimes "222mock 222", and i need just replace 'mock'

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` (i.e. `gawk`) you could do:

```
gawk -i inplace '/mock/ { getline < "mock.txt" } 1' test{1..3}.txt
```

Like `sed`, `gawk` offers inplace editing. The above command looks for the regex-pattern `mock`, and when it finds it, it replaces it with the next line from `mock.txt`. The `1` is a pattern that always matches, and thus causes `gawk` to perform its default action, which is to print the (newly) read line. Note that you won't actually see this line during inplace-editing; the print-action is necessary for the output to be recorded.